# CSS: Making a non-root block element occupy the whole page

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is it possible with only CSS to make a block element occupy the whole page("busy box") when the element is on a non-root level where width and height set to 100% stretch it only as big as the parent element?

I could have done it using absolute size but that would require javascript to adjust to the current size of the page.

This may look like I should have added the element at the root level if I want it to occupy the whole page but I can't modify the master page because we're reusing a standard SharePoint one.

**@Edit:** For some reason non of the two answers are working for me, must me a CSS quirk, I'll look for the other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find out the current size of the page. Instead, try:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

Comment: That won't work if an ancestor element is positioned absolutely or relative.

Comment: DN: The link is to a question about certification.

Comment: @Residuum: hence the "try" and not "this will definitely work", because I don't know what his markup looks like.

Comment: @axk lol! Sorry, clipboard didn't update. Here you go, IE6 workaround included: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

Comment: Does not work in my case for some reason (IE7), the box becomes invisible when I remove the 100% with and height and add the right and bottom).

Answer (score 1):

What *should* work is `position:fixed`. The issue with this is IE6, but there are some solutions: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html . Fixed positioning should take the element out of flow and position it according to the window. For more on positioning: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

Of course, I'm assuming you want it to take up the whole viewport and *stay there*, and that whatever you want to display where it is will be within the element itself. Those are a lot of assumptions. As you might guess from the name, fixed positioning sticks the element where you put it--on top of everything else, and it won't move as you scroll.

Comment: Not working for some reason, when I have it set to absolute with width and height set to 100% I can see the "busy box" (not occupying the whole viewport though), when I change to "fixed" the box is no more visible.

Comment: @axk You need to provide more information, then. Your issue is somewhere else in your CSS.